# How can I change the selected date in this calendar widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, onchange, setstate

I am trying to make a calendar widget where one date can be selected, I can set the selected date with hardcode but I want to be able to change the selected date from the inner Widget (DayWidget).

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class HorizontalCalendar extends StatefulWidget {
  final double height;
  final double width;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final EdgeInsets margin;
  final int month;
  final int year;
  final int selectedDate;
  HorizontalCalendar({
    @required this.year,
    @required this.month,
    this.selectedDate,
    this.height,
    this.width,
    this.margin = const EdgeInsets.all(0),
    this.padding = const EdgeInsets.all(0),
  });
  @override
  _HorizontalCalendarState createState() => _HorizontalCalendarState();
}

class _HorizontalCalendarState extends State<HorizontalCalendar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: widget.width,
      height: widget.height,
      margin: widget.margin,
      padding: widget.padding,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: DateTime(widget.year, widget.month + 1, 0).day,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          index = index + 1;
          DateTime date = DateTime(widget.year, widget.month, index);
          return DayWidget(
            day: index,
            dayName: DateFormat('EEEE').format(date).substring(0, 3),
            selected: widget.selectedDate == index ? true : false,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

DayWidget:

```
class DayWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int day;
  final String dayName;
  final bool selected;
  DayWidget({this.day, this.dayName, this.selected = false});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.17,
        child: FlatButton(
          color: selected ? Colors.white : Colors.transparent,
          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              side: BorderSide(
                  color: selected ? Colors.white : Colors.grey,
                  width: 1,
                  style: BorderStyle.solid)),
          onPressed: () {
            // Here I should be able to change the selected date from
            // The HorizontalCalendar
          },
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                dayName,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: selected ? Colors.blueGrey : Colors.white60,
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: selected ? FontWeight.w900 : FontWeight.w300),
              ),
              Text(
                day.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: selected ? Colors.blueGrey : Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 24,
                    fontWeight: selected ? FontWeight.w900 : FontWeight.w500),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image of the widget for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OWgw.png)

Im trying to change the selected date when the DayWidget is pressed, but i do not seem to have access to the HorizontalCalendar Widget, i tried to make a method static, but if i make a method inside the HorizontalCalendar static I cannot use setState to update the view.

Please guide me into a better way to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First we need to **move** selectedDate to mutable variable. we need to re-declare it on `_HorizontalCalendarState` class.

```dart
class HorizontalCalendar extends StatefulWidget {
  final double height;
  final double width;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final EdgeInsets margin;
  final int month;
  final int year;
  final int selectedDate; // this is immutable
  HorizontalCalendar({
    @required this.year,
    @required this.month,
    this.selectedDate,
    this.height,
    this.width,
    this.margin = const EdgeInsets.all(0),
    this.padding = const EdgeInsets.all(0),
  });
  @override
  _HorizontalCalendarState createState() => _HorizontalCalendarState();
}

class _HorizontalCalendarState extends State<HorizontalCalendar> {

  int selectedDay; // this is mutable

  @override
  void initState() {
    selectedDay = widget.selectedDate;
    super.initState();
  }
```

2. Secondly, we can pass callback to DayWidget.

```dart
return DayWidget(
  day: index,
  dayName: DateFormat('EEEE').format(date).substring(0, 3),
  selected: selectedDay == index ? true : false, // modify this
  callback: (int day) { // Add this
    selectedDay = day;
    setState((){});
  },
);
```

3. Finally, we can callback within DayWidget :

```dart
onPressed: () {
  callback(day);
  // Here I should be able to change the selected date from
  // The HorizontalCalendar
},
```

**This is the result :**

[image: Demo]

4. Full Code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class HorizontalCalendar extends StatefulWidget {
  final double height;
  final double width;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final EdgeInsets margin;
  final int month;
  final int year;
  final int selectedDate; // this is immutable
  HorizontalCalendar({
    @required this.year,
    @required this.month,
    this.selectedDate,
    this.height,
    this.width,
    this.margin = const EdgeInsets.all(0),
    this.padding = const EdgeInsets.all(0),
  });
  @override
  _HorizontalCalendarState createState() => _HorizontalCalendarState();
}

class _HorizontalCalendarState extends State<HorizontalCalendar> {

  int selectedDay; // this is mutable

  @override
  void initState() {
    selectedDay = widget.selectedDate;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: widget.width,
      height: widget.height,
      margin: widget.margin,
      padding: widget.padding,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: DateTime(widget.year, widget.month + 1, 0).day,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          index = index + 1;
          DateTime date = DateTime(widget.year, widget.month, index);
          return DayWidget(
            day: index,
            dayName: DateFormat('EEEE').format(date).substring(0, 3),
            selected: selectedDay == index ? true : false,
            callback: (int day) {
              selectedDay = day;
              setState((){});
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DayWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int day;
  final String dayName;
  final bool selected;
  final Function(int) callback;
  DayWidget({
    this.day,
    this.dayName,
    this.selected = false,
    this.callback,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.17,
        child: FlatButton(
          color: selected ? Colors.white : Colors.transparent,
          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
            side: BorderSide(
                color: selected ? Colors.white : Colors.grey,
                width: 1,
                style: BorderStyle.solid),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            callback(day);
            // Here I should be able to change the selected date from
            // The HorizontalCalendar
          },
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                dayName,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: selected ? Colors.blueGrey : Colors.white60,
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontWeight: selected ? FontWeight.w900 : FontWeight.w300,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                day.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: selected ? Colors.blueGrey : Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 24,
                  fontWeight: selected ? FontWeight.w900 : FontWeight.w500,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: that would make it selected which is fine, but it will not remove the selection from the other widget. i mean there can be only one selected widget at a time, i cannot select multiple days in the calendar

Comment: I've added demo in my answer for your apps. Is that what you looking for ?

Comment: yes, this is exactly what im looking for. can you provide full code ? for some reason im not getting it right.

Comment: sure !, here I've updated my answer. you can accept it as answer then